# Elastic Search: Multiple queries and boosting

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make a search containing many searches with different boosts, and having the results returned by score. I tried making a search as follows, and I thought it worked very well, until I realized that only the first query was being run.

How should I rephrase this to have a result with all the queries run, and the results ordered by score, where the scores will be added together if a result shows up for multiple queries?

```
[{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "title": {
                "value": "lord",
                "boost": 20,
                "min_similarity": 0.8
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "location": {
                "value": "london",
                "boost": 1000,
                "min_similarity": 0.8
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "haircolour": {
                "value": "dark",
                "boost": 500,
                "min_similarity": 0.8
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "description": {
                "value": "senior",
                "boost": 100,
                "min_similarity": 0.7
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "description": {
                "value": "manager",
                "boost": 100,
                "min_similarity": 0.7
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score -1):

Why not creating a bool query for each query with your main query as a must clause and other queries as should clauses?

Does it help?